# ganache-cli child process dependency not found

Tags: node.js, ethereum

I am trying to use ganache and web3.js inside Token wizard application.

I run an instance of the ganache-cli in my terminal and then create an instance of web3.js using ganache as a provider using this code:

```
try {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
        this.setState({
          approvePermissions: true,
          web3: window.web3
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('There was a problem fetching accounts', err)
      }
```

as I launch my application, I get the following error:

```
Error in ganache-cli
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\wiz\node_modules\ganache-cli\build'
```

Any one has idea to solve it?

Comment: Please paste your code too.

Comment: @lependu I added the code